# 3D models as controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d, wpf-controls

In my latest crazy project I'm trying to create a view for a 3D strategy-like game. It's 3D, so the main part of the view is a `Viewport3D`. In it, there are several `Model3Ds` for the units. The thing is, I'd like to use the 3D view interactively (for example selecting units by clicking on them one by one), so I've wrapped my models in `ContainerUIElement3Ds`. At first there are only a few models in my view, but later there can be more, so I don't want to hard code them into the view. My first approach was to create a `Control` that holds one model and handles interactions on it, but this plan seemed to fail, since `ContainerUIElement3D` is a sealed class, and `Model3D` can't catch the events I need.

So how could I workaround this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two general approaches:

1. Use real interactive elements in 3D
2. Use simple graphical elements with hit-testing

Both approaches have value and it's up to you if either meets your needs.

Just to know that it's possible to use real interactive elements, as an advanced technique, is valuable information.  Here's a starting point for your research into this area:

- [Josh Smith: Interactive Animated 2D Elements in a 3D ItemsControl](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/04/01/interactive-animated-2d-elements-in-a-3d-itemscontrol/)

The article describes an `ItemsControl` but that is going even further that you asked.  The concepts are what is important to you and the other article links you'll find on that site.

The brute-force approach of hit-testing your graphical elements and rendering all the interactivity yourself might sound daunting, but for a game you often want complete control over the elements.  You might have your own plan for rendering selected items, etc with abstract colors or halos.

There infrastructure of say, a button, is not that complicated and you can implement click and mouse over handling with just a few code working directly with rectangles or cubes.  If this "do it yourself" approach sounds good to you, all you need is 3D hit-testing.  Here's an article to get you started:

- [WPF3D Team Blog: 3D Hit Testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf3d/archive/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

WPF 3D is not for complicated games.
But...
There are two ways (as Rick Sladkey noticed) to get interactive behavior:

1. Inherit from UIElement3D - full support of interactivity
2. Inherit from ModelVisual3D - VisualTreeHelper using (hit testing for example)

So, your Units are instances of this classes (p.1 or 2)
The deal is 3D complexity of your Units.
If they have simple meshes and not so hard materials you will feel free with amount of units till 1000-2000 and even more.

[image]

Simple materials, light weight meshes and inherited from UIElement3D.
But scene become [image]hard a bit if we change materials...

**Opinion**

Inherit from UIElement3D

**Advice**

if it is possible, do not use 3party libraries, write 3D objects in code by hand. The reason is the some of them is incorrect in part of performance.